# Aurelia js add npm package

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, dependencies, aurelia

I want to use the following npm package  https://www.npmjs.com/package/poker-evaluator
It can also be found on github: github.com/chenosaurus/poker-evaluator

On the project folder I ran the following command line, npm install poker-evaluator --save

And it seems that I installed the library -> [Package Json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faB7E.jpg)

I want to be able to run the functions from this module(poker-evaluator) and I can't insert this module.

tried multiple times and in different ways ...

Comment: This is how I tried http://prntscr.com/ewgn5q

Clearly I am doing something very wrong.

Comment: Are you using Webpack or the Aurelia CLI?

Comment: Hello Ashley Grant,

I am using Aurelia CLI

Comment: Ah. In that case, you're going to need to add the package (and its dependencies) to your `aurelia.json` file. I'll explain in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the package you are looking at relies on NodeJS APIs, so it cannot be used in the browser. If you look at its source, you'll see: https://github.com/chenosaurus/poker-evaluator/blob/master/lib/PokerEvaluator.js#L1

```
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
```

These are Node APIs that work with files. You'll have to use this package on your server and wrap it with an API that your Aurelia application will talk to.

Comment: Hmm, it seems things are more complicated than I thought with Aurelia :)
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: It's not really an Aurelia problem. It's that that code was written to run on the server. You wouldn't be able to get it to work in the browser with any front end framework or vanilla JS. Sorry about that.